# Bootstrap 5: Text box overlaying and Image at the center

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, grid, bootstrap-5

How can I do a layout in Bootstrap 5 such as the following:

[image]

I tried to do it by playing with the provided margin & position classes, but does react nicely in responsive environment.

```
<div class="section bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8 order-last" style="z-index: 1;">
                <div class="content-image float-end"><img src="http://placehold.it/769x600" class="img-fluid"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" style="z-index: 2;">
                <div class="p-5 bg-light-olive" style="margin-top: 45%; margin-right: -45%;">
                    <h1>Content Heading</h1>
                    <p>Content Description</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-white">Action</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: share your html code

Comment: @navnath added the html